# position absolute iPad container width issue

Tags: css, css-position

I am having an issue viewing in iPad safari where my container div is resizing to fit an absolute positioned element. iPad seems to be adding the overflowing element's width to the ".content" 980 width and zooming out to show about a 1080px width. Perhaps there is a property to force the iPad to only size to the 980px width of content?

I have a container div with class of content with the following css properties defined:

```
.content{
    position:relative;
    width:980px;
    height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.e1{left:880px;top:892px;width:300px}
```

Within content I have an absolute positioned element that goes outside of the bounds of 980px width like so:

```
<div class="content">   
   <div class="e1">
      <img src="images/elements/e1.png"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

[image: iPad Safari Screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem and was able to fix it using the code below, hope this helps...

```
html,body
{
width: 100%;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Good thought but did not fix the issue in my case.

Comment: Fixed it for my case! I couldn't use the content="width=980" because I wanted the site to also be for iPhone and large desktop screens. But make sure to add position:absolute; to your image.

Answer (score 4):

add this to your head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=980, user-scalable=0" />
```

Edit:

Ok, having looked at your code and the screen, I can see that the element isn't actually absolute positioned as you've set top and left but haven't included "position:absolute;". Anywho, it seems the issue is the width of the image so add this to your css

```
.e1 img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Comment: This did not fix it, iPad is still adding the overflow width to the .content 980px width

Comment: Your answer seems logical and would probably fix in most cases but still not fixing my issue. The difference of the absolute positioned element seems to be getting added to the content width.

Comment: I've decided to go another route and have created a dedicated iPad version of the site because of some other script issues that I was having. Thank you for your help!